# Can't install gambit python api on windows

Tags: python, windows, game-theory

I am trying to use gambit to look at game theory. I have successfully installed the program gambit from SourceForge. My trouble is with installing the api for python.

First, it isn't the same library you get from using pip. That gambit is a totally different one.

Second, the instructions from [here](http://www.gambit-project.org/gambit13/build.html#build-python) seem out of date, and also I can't find the setup.py files in the gambit folder.

Any advice on how to install this in windows would be helpful.

Comment: `Gambit 13` has a `.msi` extension software for windows on `SourceForge`

Comment: @KartikeySingh Which version? 13.0.0 thru 13.1.2 are available. Also, are you saying that the python extension is on the same msi as the gambit main profile?

Comment: @KartikeySingh `Gambit 15` also has a `.msi` software. Installing Gambit isn't the problem. The problem is going from that to installing the api module for Python.